# Will variable name with underscore call function same name but camelCase automatically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, naming-conventions

Can I call a function which have camelCase same name as a variable in laravel?
For e.g. `$email_referral_url` and function name is `getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` 
The function is defined into Entity.

Comment: Yes. Though in this case, `getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` is most likely a class function within a model, so can only be accessed via `$model->getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` or `$model->email_referral_url`. In the case of Eloquent, the latter actually calls the former.

Comment: `getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` is an accessor(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) Lets say this function is defined in a model called `$m`, then if you call `$m->email_referral_url` laravel delegates the the call to the `getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` function. You can call the function manually like `$m->getEmailReferralUrlAttribute()` but that defeats the point of an accessor :)